# Increase ffmpeg precision for filters like SSIM, PSNR

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

I am trying to calculate the ssim and psnr of an image using ffmpeg; however, the results are only upto 2 decimal places. Is there a way to increase the precision of the results (higher the better)?

Output:

```py
n:1 mse_avg:0.00 mse_r:0.00 mse_g:0.00 mse_b:0.00 psnr_avg:76.89 psnr_r:76.88 psnr_g:76.93 psnr_b:76.86
```

Command used for psnr:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i original.tiff -i modified.tiff -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnr_logfile.txt -f null -
```

Command used for ssim:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i original.tiff -i modified.tiff -lavfi ssim=stats_file=ssim_logfile.txt -f null -
```

Comment: SSIM/PSNR vlaues are not so precision that you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console output shows more decimal places:

```
ffmpeg -i modified.tiff -i original.tiff -lavfi "[0][1]psnr" -f null -
...
[Parsed_psnr_0 @ 0x55bad8baeb80] PSNR r:29.920378 g:33.903905 b:29.960557 average:30.906865 min:30.906865 max:30.906865
```

Or use the [libvmaf filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf):

```
ffmpeg -i modified.tiff -i original.tiff -lavfi "[0][1]libvmaf=psnr=1:ssim=1:log_path=stats.json:log_fmt=json" -f null -
```

The example `stats.json` contains:

```
"VMAF score":84.32680682547482,
"PSNR score":36.81582411904382,
"SSIM score":0.9912355542182922
```

Comment: Using the libvmaf filter, I get the following errors `libvmaf WARNING could not read model from path: "/usr/local/share/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl"
libvmaf WARNING pkl model files have been deprecated, use json
libvmaf ERROR problem loading model file: /usr/local/share/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl`. Can you please advise? I'm on windows and it seems it is using a linux path.

Comment: @Rashiq That's an independent issue apart from the original question. Should be asked as a new question. Try [su] if you want to avoid the off-topic downvoters. I'll see the question there too.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I eventually just hex-edited the ffmpeg shared filter library to change the format string.

Comment: Can you go over the steps on how to do it? That would be more helpful as an answer.